# How to check some properties values and other properties only existence?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, chai

Using chaijs, how do I check that some properties of the object are equal to something and other properties only exists in one?

Something like

```
return expect(profilePromise)
        .to.eventually.be.fulfilled
        .to.have.property('__data')
        .to.any.deep.equal({
          id: Number, <--------- here
          firstName: facebookProfile.first_name,
          lastName: facebookProfile.last_name,
          email: facebookProfile.email,
          gender: facebookProfile.gender,
          isPopularVerified: facebookProfile.is_verified,
          isVerified: facebookProfile.verified,
          locale: facebookProfile.locale,
          timezone: facebookProfile.timezone,

          createdOn: Number, <--------- here
          updatedOn: Number, <--------- here
        })
```

I want to know that I have `id`, `createdOn` and `updatedOn` properties, but I actually do not care about its values.

Thank you

Comment: This is where Chai lacks in comparison to Jasmine, [see this](https://github.com/chaijs/chai/issues/644). I guess currently this can be treated by a custom assertion, or deep equal can be changed to deep include.

Comment: @estus oh, ok. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pattern match. [Chai JSON Pattern](https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/chai-json-pattern/) plugin can help you to do this.

E.g.

```js
const chai = require('chai');
const chaiJsonPattern = require('chai-json-pattern').default;
const chaiAsPromised = require('chai-as-promised');

chai.use(chaiJsonPattern);
chai.use(chaiAsPromised);

const { expect } = chai;

describe('38598544', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    const profilePromise = Promise.resolve({
      __data: {
        id: Math.random(),
        firstName: 'facebookProfile.first_name',
        lastName: 'facebookProfile.last_name',
        email: 'facebookProfile.email',
        gender: 'facebookProfile.gender',
        isPopularVerified: 'facebookProfile.is_verified',
        isVerified: 'facebookProfile.verified',
        locale: 'facebookProfile.locale',
        timezone: 'facebookProfile.timezone',
        createdOn: Date.now(),
        updatedOn: Date.now(),
      },
    });

    return expect(profilePromise).to.eventually.be.fulfilled.to.have.property('__data').to.matchPattern(`{
      "id": Number,
      "firstName": "facebookProfile.first_name",
      "lastName": "facebookProfile.last_name",
      "email": "facebookProfile.email",
      "gender": "facebookProfile.gender",
      "isPopularVerified": "facebookProfile.is_verified",
      "isVerified": "facebookProfile.verified",
      "locale": "facebookProfile.locale",
      "timezone": "facebookProfile.timezone",

      "createdOn": Number,
      "updatedOn": Number,
    }`);
  });
});
```

test result:

```
  38598544
    ✓ should pass


  1 passing (28ms)
```